# How to copy costumers and orders into development system?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, database

We copied our shop into a development system and made some big changes. Now we are tested everything and would like to update the database with the latest changes from the live system (costumers and orders) so we would switch live and development system. As we made changes to CMS and configuration we can not switch the whole database.

Who can we copy orders and customers from shop to shop?

**Update**

I found a [blog](http://blog.maximusbusiness.com/2013/11/move-magento-sales-customers/) describing this can be done by copying the listed db tables. But as far as I know directly accessing the database is bad. Would this work or is there are better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import those tables, as long as your changes don't affect them and after you have identified any tables used by extensions that relate to sales and customers. This includes newsletter and product models by the way. So pretty much the entire system.

It is certainly not the preferred way of doing things. And extensions we've tried in the past to handle these kind of imports either have side effects like creating a customer account for anonymous orders or take several hours to complete for relatively small sets if data.

For the future look [at this blog post](http://www.customerparadigm.com/six-types-of-magento-product-types/). Working with setup scripts means your changes are applied on a fresh import of the production database. If you don't like coding every change by hand, look into [Genmato Configuration Versioning.](https://genmato.com/setup-script-versioning)